# Android Java: changing image in listview depending on content

Tags: java, android, image, listview, user-interface

after quite a googling without a luck I come here again to bother you all :)

I have ListView that in my app that is populated via SQLitle db from cursor.. looks like this:

```
public void updateShiftList(String x) {
    db.openToRead();

    listShifts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listShifts);

    // get data

    cursor = db.getPlan(x);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    // set adapter
    String[] from = { dataManager.KEY_SHIFT, dataManager.KEY_DATE };
    int[] to = { R.id.rowShift, R.id.rowDate };

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

    listShifts.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();

}
```

in row.xml I have image before each row and I would like to implement function or check method during creation of this ListView that would change the image depending on some parameters that I would test, eg R.id.rowDate == TodayDate ( there is date in that text field ) or if the R.id.rowDate is next date from today....

How could I do that, or where... is there some Overide that could be used ? I'm learning java on this simple project as I'm doing it so be gentle :)

Thanks all,
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from my code. I use it in many projects of mine, that collect data from database and display them in a ListView. It works. You my need to adapt it slightly to your project. Anyway I would recommend to rewrite your code.
Image stuff is at the bottom:

```
package my.package;

import android.app.Activity;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {


private DBAdapter mDb;

private ListView mListView;
private Cursor mCursor;   



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.groups_list);       

    mDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    mDb.open();       

    populateListView();
}    

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(mCursor != null)
        mCursor.close();
    mCursor = null;

    if(mDb != null)
        mDb.close();        
    mDb = null;       
}    


private void populateListView(){        

    if(mCursor!=null)  //close the old one first
        mCursor.close();
    mCursor = mDb.getSomeDataCursor();                

    MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, R.layout.groups_list_item, mCursor, false);        
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}    


 private class MainAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter{

    private int mLayout;
    private int mColumnIndexGroup;

    public MainAdapter(Context pContext, int pLayout, Cursor pCursor, boolean pAutoRequery) {
        super(pContext, pLayout, pCursor, pAutoRequery);

        mLayout = pLayout;
        mColumnIndexGroup = (pCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_NAME)); 
    }        

    @Override
    public View newView(Context pContext, Cursor pCursor, ViewGroup pParent) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return li.inflate(mLayout, pParent, false);
    }        

    @Override
    public void bindView(View pView, Context pContext, Cursor pCursor) {           
        TextView tvGroup = (TextView)pView.findViewById(R.id.groupsListTVGroup);
        tvGroup.setText(pCursor.getString(mColumnIndexGroup));

        //Image stuff - an example
        if(pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex(SOMETHING)) == SOME_VAL){
            ImageView img = (ImageView) pView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage)
        }
   }     

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I didn't know you can make your own adapter.

Comment: I managed to make it work ! One more question what for is that 'newView' Override ? In many examples I have seen that there is almost the same code as in 'bindView' I even try to use it without it and it worked... not sure what is it for. I would be very grateful for simple explanation, thanks.

Comment: From what I see in the official docs, newView is to inflate views from XML (and in simple cases might be not needed as you noticed, I am not sure), and bindView is to put data from the cursor to the views.

Answer (score 1):

And again...

Build a custom Adapter that uses your data...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

**Example**

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/